# error phpmyadmin #2000 - LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE is forbidden, check mysqli.allow_local_infile

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

when we import a csv by phpmyadmin using "csv using load data", we have this error in phpmyadmin and the import into our table from the csv is not done.
phpmyadmin version 4.4.15.10

With another version of phpmyadmin 4.4.15.8 with the same database and my same data server we have no problem.

thank you for your answers

Requête SQL :

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/phpRH1Q9u' INTO TABLE `glpi_corresp_usernames` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
MySQL a répondu: Documentation

#2000 - LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE is forbidden, check mysqli.allow_local_infile


 phpMyAdminWarning in ./libraries/dbi/DBIMysqli.class.php#262
 mysqli_query(): LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE forbidden

Backtrace

./libraries/dbi/DBIMysqli.class.php#262: mysqli_query(
object,
string 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \'/tmp/phpRH1Q9u\' INTO TABLE `glpi_corresp_usernames` FIELDS TERMINATED BY \';\' ENCLOSED BY \'"\' ESCAPED BY \'\\\\\' LINES TERMINATED BY \'\\r\\n\'',
integer 0,
)
./libraries/DatabaseInterface.class.php#183: PMA_DBI_Mysqli->realQuery(
string 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \'/tmp/phpRH1Q9u\' INTO TABLE `glpi_corresp_usernames` FIELDS TERMINATED BY \';\' ENCLOSED BY \'"\' ESCAPED BY \'\\\\\' LINES TERMINATED BY \'\\r\\n\'',
object,
integer 0,
)
./libraries/import.lib.php#170: PMA_DatabaseInterface->tryQuery(string 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \'/tmp/phpRH1Q9u\' INTO TABLE `glpi_corresp_usernames` FIELDS TERMINATED BY \';\' ENCLOSED BY \'"\' ESCAPED BY \'\\\\\' LINES TERMINATED BY \'\\r\\n\'')
./libraries/plugins/import/ImportLdi.class.php#158: PMA_importRunQuery()
./import.php#615: ImportLdi->doImport(array)
```

Comment: phpmyadmin 4.4 is a very old version. Have you considered upgrading to the latest version?

Comment: Hello for the moment unfortunately I can not update the version!.  ! I'm a bit of a annoyance

Comment: Check your php.ini for `mysqli.allow_local_infile = On`

Answer (score 0):

This helped my situation in phpMyAdmin:

1. run this command: `show global variables like 'local_infile';`
2. if value if `OFF` run: `set global local_infile=true;`
3. Then like @Guido Faecke said Check your `php.ini` for `mysqli.allow_local_infile = On`
4. in this line remove semicolon -> `;mysqli.allow_local_infile = On`
5. restart apache and then you can run

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE...
```